# Why is reported database size (on disk?) different from that in memory

Tags: mysql, innodb

My database contains three tables, having 50k, 50k and 5m rows. All of them are InnoDB. (largest one contains varchar[256]). The size of my database is 214MB, which I got by querying `information_schema.TABLES` (I guess this gives the size of data+index on disk?)

I had 1.5GB of RAM and I thought I'll convert the engine of all tables to MEMORY. But when I started converting the largest table, I got 1114 error.

After some research, I found that `max_heap_table_size` as only 16MB. So, I set the `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size` to 1GB.

When I tried converting again, I saw the memory usage of **mysqld.exe** process go beyond 1.2GB and then it threw same error again before even converting half the rows! I removed half the rows from the largest table and it finally fit in - at 700MB in memory!!

**Why is a database that is 214MB, not even able to fit in more than 4 times the memory?**

Is there anything else inside the process that is eating up the memory other than the data+index?

*Machine: Intel P4 - 1.9GHz, 1.5GB RAM, Win7 Ultimate.*

Comment: @Randy But not so much that it will stop the tables being loaded into RAM completely. @OP There may be a large amount of RAM allocated to cache or something else. Have a look at `top` and/or `htop` to see what's using your RAM. Are you running on shared hosting, or a VPS?

Comment: Yes, but the memory usage I reported is for the mysqld.exe process alone. Everything else in my system fit nicely in the few hundred megs that remained. Even if I had like 4GB and somehow made it all fit in, my main question is: why 214MB takes up >1.2GB in RAM

Comment: @JamWaffles Actually this is happening in my temporary Win7 dev machine. I was looking at task manager. The memory for mysqld.exe before starting conversion was steady at 144M. Once conversion started, it zoomed past 1.2G within 20sec then error.

Comment: You can check if you have similar behaviour by exporting the data, creating new tables with MEMORY engine and importing trying to import that data. You must remember however that restarting the mysql process will remove all data from those tables.

Comment: @Zefiryn I tried both ways. 1) Changing engine in table properties, as well as 2) creating a MEMORY table and inserting into it from old table. **Same behavior, same memory usage pattern!**. Only difference was I got the same error in a different dialog :|

Comment: Do you have some indicies set up for those tables besides the primary key?

Comment: @Zefiryn Yes, I had. Thats what I thought too. But removing all the indices didn't make any difference either :( BUT.. on a side note, the 214M is supposed to give us the data+index size isn't it?

Comment: @SenthilKumar, have you considered that maybe the process of creating an in memory table requires a lot of memory, and not necessarily the table itself?

Comment: @kurtzbot That is exactly what I thought of when I decided to try with smaller table. But if it were true, after loading half-sized table successfully and occupying 700MB in the process, it should have come down, ideally. (see the part in my question where I mention the stats for half size table). **But it didn't come down**. Maybe some cleanup not happening after conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this dba.se question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11912/how-much-memory-will-a-memory-table-take-up), in which the accepted answer had a link to [this dev.mysql page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html), which says:

> *MEMORY tables use a fixed-length row-storage format. Variable-length
>   types such as VARCHAR are stored using a fixed length.*

Like I mentioned in the question, I had a table with 5m rows with one varchar[256] column.

**5,000,000 x 256 = 1.19G (assuming 1 byte per char)**, so I think that's the answer!

That particular column alone contributed to 95% of the space, and the rest were from the other numeric columns. I guess InnoDB did not store it in fixed length on disk. And because the field mostly had test values that did not go past 10 - 15 chars, it occupied such a small size on disk.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you go about converting from InnoDB to MEMORY? If it's because performance, it's better to increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: Actually, yes! I was desperately trying to do this *before* I arrived at the correct buffer size for InnoDB for my database; I've never before dealt with 5 million records in a table. Now I have InnoDB working properly, but I still wanted to know why this was happening :)